# Spring Sleuth getting exception for POST requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

Spring Sleuth GET Request is working fine.
When trying to integrate with POST request it is failing.

```
    2019-02-14 13:31:11.007  INFO [notification-Service,,,] 4044 --- [io-40303-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 17 ms
2019-02-14 13:31:11.141 ERROR [notification-Service,6b0b3a786d79d79f,6b0b3a786d79d79f,false] 4044 --- [io-40303-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Session event listener threw exception

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSessionListener.sessionCreated(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent;)V
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.tellNew(StandardSession.java:388) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.setId(StandardSession.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.setId(StandardSession.java:341) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.createSession(ManagerBase.java:686) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:3018) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2416) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:908) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.java:136) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.java:121) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [wiremock-standalone-2.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [wiremock-standalone-2.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:50) [spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:86) [brave-instrumentation-servlet-5.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Comment: Doesnt have enough information to help. Kindly add some code(versions used), configuration/setup to get help. Explain a bit about the flow

Comment: where you have used HttpSessionEvent ? share that piece of code. share the listener code

Answer (score 0):

This one is quite tricky

The interface is simple:

```
public interface HttpSessionListener extends EventListener {

    public default void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se);

    public default void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se);
}
```

But if we look at [Apache Tomcat's implementation of WsSessionListener](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/java/org/apache/tomcat/websocket/server/WsSessionListener.java), we can see that it is missing the `sessionCreated` method, thus the JVM assumes the class is *abstract*

```
public class WsSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener{

    private final WsServerContainer wsServerContainer;


    public WsSessionListener(WsServerContainer wsServerContainer) {
        this.wsServerContainer = wsServerContainer;
    }


    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        wsServerContainer.closeAuthenticatedSession(se.getSession().getId());
    }
}
```

So how does Apache Tomcat compile their own code?
In the [Apache Tomcat implementation of the same interface](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/java/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.java#L39-L49), they have declared these methods as `default` thus implementing classes do not have to declare these methods.

```
    public default void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    }

    public default void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    }
```

The solution to your problem would be to remove the Servlet API dependency from your build script.

```
provided "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0"
```

if you still need that API, replace it with Apache Tomcat's

```
provided "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:9.0.19"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@RestController
```

@RequestMapping("/rest/hello")
public class HelloResource {

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloResource.class);

@GetMapping(value = "/server")
public String hello() {
    LOGGER.info("Reached Server");
    return "HelloWorld";
}

@PostMapping(path = "/members", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public void addMember(@RequestBody SendSmsRequestDto sendSmsRequestDto,HttpSession session) {
    LOGGER.info("sending SMS to contacts--" + sendSmsRequestDto);
}
```

}

In above hello() controller method is showing sleuth span Id and Trace Id.
whereas addMember() controller method is throwing exception 
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSessionListener.sessionCreated(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent;)